# JSP file in eclipse corrupted. What may have happened?

Tags: eclipse, jsp

Four out of nine jsp files in the same folder is altered, and I cannot figure out why.
Something to note is only scripting elements in the jsp file is altered but all the html tags are safe.

My original code looked something like this:

```
<%System.out.println("Java command on JSP file running");%>
<%/* List<OrganizerVO> allList = (List<OrganizerVO>) session.getAttribute("saAttribute"); */%>
```

Now it looks like this:
`

```
<%
                            p
                             System.out.println("Java command on JSP file running"
                            %>
        <%
        p
         /* List<OrganizerVO> allList = (List<OrganizerVO>) session.getAttribute("saAttribute");
        %>
```

`
Almost all the scripting elements have similar changes, the beginning and end characters is cut off and replaced by spaces and also the letter 't' or 'p'.

These are not significant damages because my codes are simple, and everything in the middle of the scripting elements are intact and can be easily identified its original state, but I am worried that this might happen again.

Comment: Using "Compare with > Local History" might at least tell you when it happened.

Comment: @greg-449 Thanks for the reply! I am not familiar with this feature, but I don't seem to see the characters added (default color green) on any specific versions. 
I can only see where between two versions of the file, the change happened.